# Embed Vimeo Player (or any iframe video player) full width and height

Tags: css, responsive, vimeo, react-player

I basically want to have an embedded Vimeo video take up the full width and height of a given page (or it's parent div).  The embedded Vimeo is an iframe and I am using react-player plugin to embed the video .

I've seen these examples of responsive width vimeo videos: https://jsfiddle.net/e6w3rtj1/.  Setting the padding bottom or top to the aspect ratio percentage.  However, this only fixes the issue for the width.  I basically want the `object-fit: fill` option on images and videos for this iframe.  Is it possible?  Has anyone come across a solution?

Comment: Don't you mean object-fit: cover ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that there's a pure css solution to this problem involving media queries on aspect ratios.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <iframe/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

iframe {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   objectFit: fill, 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

   @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
      width: 177.78vh;
   }

   @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
      height: 56.25vw;
   }
}
```